# Why the input is slow here with react-hook-form, what should be optimized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Here I showed the component. On every input it goes to filter some data and provide options for select. Though on change function uses `useMemo`, but still there is a little speed lag while I type into the field.

As much as I could figure out, the function which affects the speed the most is `methods.setValue(name,value)` , which comes from the form context.

I tried also to use debounce function, but so far it didn't work, probably I'll need to see the proper usage. But probably it is not right approach at all.

What can I do to improve the speed to normal?

```
 export default function Food({
      ....
      name,
      .....
    }: FoodProps) {
      const methods = useFormContext()
      const [macros, setMacros] = useState<any>({
        proteins: 0,
        fat: 0,
        net_carbs: 0,
        sugar: 0,
        fiber: 0,
        total_carbs: 0,
        calories: 0
      })
      const [selectedTemplate, setSelectedTemplate] = useState<any>(null)
      const [wasEdited, setWasEdited] = useState(false)
    
      const info = useWatch({
        control: methods.control,
        name: `${name}.info`
      })
    
      const onChange = (fieldName: string, value: string | boolean | number) => {
        methods.setValue(fieldName, value, { shouldValidate: true })
      }
    
      const { foods } = useTemplateFoods({ clientId: 'all' })
    
      const days = useWatch({
        name: `days`,
        control: methods.control
      })
    
      const [foodName] = useWatch({
        control: methods.control,
        name: [`${name}.name`]
      })

      const getTwoDecimal = (value: any) => {
        return Math.round((value + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
      }
    
      const multiplyMacros = (grams: any) => {
        methods.setValue(
          `${name}.info.proteins`,
          getTwoDecimal(macros.proteins * (grams / 100) || 0)
        )
        methods.setValue(
          `${name}.info.fat`,
          getTwoDecimal(macros.fat * (grams / 100) || 0)
        )
        methods.setValue(
          `${name}.info.net_carbs`,
          getTwoDecimal(macros.net_carbs * (grams / 100) || 0)
        )
        methods.setValue(
          `${name}.info.sugar`,
          getTwoDecimal(macros.sugar * (grams / 100) || 0)
        )
        methods.setValue(
          `${name}.info.fiber`,
          getTwoDecimal(macros.fiber * (grams / 100) || 0)
        )
      }
    
      const getFoodsOfPlan = () => {
        const mealsOfPlan = days?.reduce(
          (acc: any[], d: any) => [
            ...acc,
            ...(d.activities || d.diet_plan_day.activities || [])
          ],
          []
        )
    
        const foodsOfPlan: any[] = mealsOfPlan?.reduce(
          (item: any[], acc: any) => [...item, ...(acc.items || [])],
          []
        )
    
        return foodsOfPlan.filter((f) => !f.data.fromTemplate)
      }

     .......
    
      const nameOptions = useMemo(() => {
        const foodsOfPlan = getFoodsOfPlan()
    
        const planOptions = foodsOfPlan
          ?.filter(
            (w: any) =>
              w?.data?.name?.toLowerCase()?.includes(foodName?.toLowerCase()) &&
              w?.data?.name !== foodName
          )
          ?.map((m: any) => ({
            label: m?.data?.name,
            value: m?.data?.name
          }))
    
        const templateOptions = foods
          ?.filter(
            (w: any) =>
              w?.name?.toLowerCase()?.includes(foodName?.toLowerCase()) &&
              w?.name !== foodName
          )
          ?.map((w: any) => ({
            label: w.name,
            value: w._id
          }))
    
        const options = []
    
        if (planOptions.length) {
          options.push({
            label: 'From this Diet Plan',
            options: getUniqueItemsByProperties(planOptions, ['label'])
          })
        }
    
        if (templateOptions.length) {
          options.push({
            label: 'From Templates',
            options: getUniqueItemsByProperties(templateOptions, ['label'])
          })
        }
    
        return options.length ? options : []
      }, [days, foods])
    
      return (
        <Styles $isDragging={isDragging} ref={innerRef} {...draggableProps}>
    
          <Controller
            render={({ field: { value, name } }) => (
              <AutoCompleteInput
                id="Food-name"
                label="Food name"
                placeholder="-"
                value={value}
                onChange={(value) => {
                  methods.setValue(name, value)
                  selectedTemplate && setWasEdited(true)
                }}
                onSelect={onFoodSelected}
                options={nameOptions}
                // error={get(errors, name)}
                className={get(errors, name) ? 'invalid-field' : ''}
                shouldScrollTo={get(errors, name)}
                disabled={readOnlyForm}
              />
            )}
            name={`${name}.name`}
          />

          .......
          
        </Styles>
      )
    }
```

Here is also a code for `useTemplateFood()`, it fetched the data with useSWR:

```
export default function useTemplateFoods({
  name,
  clientId
}: IProps = {}): UseTemplateFoods & UsePagination {
  const pagination = usePagination()
  const params = {
    page: pagination.page,
    per_page: 10,
    filter: {
      name: name || '',
      account_id: clientId || ''
    }
  }

  const { data, error } = useSWR(() => getKey(params), getTemplatesData)

  const isLoading = !data && !error
  const foods = data?.data || []
  const meta = data?.meta || {}

  return {
    isLoading,
    foods,
    meta,
    ...pagination
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's profiler/timeline? Or the React dev tools' profiler?

Comment: Also: how is `useTemplateFoods` implemented? Does it return a stable `foods` (by object identity)? As we know, `useMemo` only looks at object identity, not at contents, for figuring out whether to recompute the result, so if `foods` isn't stable, `useMemo` recomputes on each update.

Comment: @AKX no, how should I use it? What to look for?

Comment: The simplest is to open the profiler, start recording, enter e.g. "abc" in your field, stop recording and then zoom into the timeline to see where time is spent.

Comment: @AKX I included useTemplateFood() in the description, please take a look. It fetches the data.

Comment: Okay - seems to be a straightforward SWR hook. And, well, of course you can add a `console.log('Recomputing names!')` to the `useMemo` body to see whether it's being recomputed a lot. But the profiler timeline is your best bet.